# Where to find the Library for ActionBarSherlock in Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am learning the `ActionBarSherlock` in Android and I saw that there lies a Library which we need to Add in our existing Project in order to use the `ActionBarSherlock` Feature.

What I am surprising at is that I have downloaded the `.zip Library` from the Website **`"actionbarsherlock.com"`** but when I didn't find any "Library" folder in it along with the other two folders namely "`Samples`" and "`Website`".

Where can I find the Library Folder which I can add in my Project?

Can anybody help me on this Please!

Thanks,
Darshan

Comment: here you go-http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html or here-https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

1 - Download da Lib and unzip.

2 - In Eclipse Import->Existing Project into Workspace, and then browse to the location where the .classpath and .project files exists for sherlock project.

3- Right-click on your project -> Properties, In Android->Library section click Add. Select Sherlock.

4 - Enjoy.

Comment: jms_I know the Procedure as You said, but I don't find the .classpath and .project file in the Project I downloaded.